# Summary and density plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, density-plot

I'm new to R and just trying to figure out how to visualise data taken from the UCDP Battle-related Deaths Dataset Version 21.1 (https://ucdp.uu.se/downloads/index.html#battlerelated). What I'm trying to do is produce a similar chart to the one in the picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XM2QA.png) but it doesn't work. I guess it must be quite simple but I got confused anyway:

```
ucdp_new <- ucdp_dataset %>% 
 mutate(conflict_type = ifelse(bd_high>1000, "War", "Minor")) %>%
 filter(year>=1990)

conflict_no <- ucdp_new %>% 
   count(year, conflict_type)

head(conflict_no)
    # A tibble: 6 x 3
      year  conflict_type     n
      <chr> <chr>           <int>
    1 1990  Minor            48
    2 1990  War              17
    3 1991  Minor            49
    4 1991  War              19
    5 1992  Minor            43
    6 1992  War              17

conflict_no %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=year, y=n, fill=conflict_type)) + 
    geom_density()
```

Apparently the result looks ridiculous because it only shows x axis and y axis.

Comment: Try with `geom_area` instead of `geom_density`.

Comment: Try `geom_area()` rather than `geom_density()` because you have already calculated the `y` values. `geom_density()` is a univatiate plot.

Comment: @stefan , @MrFlick Thank you for a quick response but, unfortunately, something is still not going right:( Surprisingly, it works relatively fine with `geom_point()` but I don't quite like the look, so the plot would certainly be better if it had a density thing.

Comment: @Pauline I guess the plot look weird because only 3 years had minor conflicts

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested in the comments switching to `geom_area` would be one option to achieve the kind of plot in the image you added as a link:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

url <- "https://ucdp.uu.se/downloads/brd/ucdp-brd-dyadic-211-csv.zip"

download.file(url, destfile = "ucdp-brd-dyadic-211-csv.zip")
unzip("ucdp-brd-dyadic-211-csv.zip")

ucdp_dataset <- read.csv("ucdp-brd-dyadic-211.csv")

ucdp_new <- ucdp_dataset %>% 
  mutate(conflict_type = ifelse(bd_high>1000, "War", "Minor")) %>%
  filter(year>=1990)

conflict_no <- ucdp_new %>% 
  count(year, conflict_type)

ggplot(conflict_no, aes(year, n, fill = conflict_type, color = conflict_type)) +
  geom_area(alpha = .8)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I must have probably missed some detail when trying to switch to `geom_area()`